# ERROR: Document processed/posted in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, openbravo

```
    SQL error:

   ERROR:  Document processed/posted
```

In statement:

```
   DELETE FROM "public"."m_inventory" WHERE "m_id"='1001270'
```

Does anyone know why and for what reason i am getting this error,Not able to delete that row

Comment: Do you have some trigger in your database that catches delete event on that table and (for some reason) returns that error?

Comment: no i have deleted other rows and i dont have any trigger.... but not able to delete this row and getting this error

Comment: @Marco's suggestion sounds sensible. Have you physically checked that you dont have a trigger on the table? The other rows you deletyed may have worked because they passed some validation check in the trigger. That error certainly doesn't look like any database error I've ever seen..

Comment: @StevieG i have checked no trigger as such

Comment: Then you're going to have to provide more detail.. is the statement executed withing stored proc? If so, please post the full code.. (are you working on OpenBravo, by any chance?)

Comment: @StevieG no stored procedure, its just this query i am running in the browser directly

Comment: @StevieG yup m working on openbravo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a trigger on the table.

http://openbravo.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/openbravo/main/file/e5c51e8fd720/src-db/database/model/triggers/M_INVENTORY_TRG.xml

```
IF DELETING THEN
  IF (:old.PROCESSED = 'Y') THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20501, 'Document processed/posted') ;
  END IF;
END IF;
```

Comment: how to delete a product from m_product , coz it has got loads of triggers and interlinked with other tables

Comment: I've got no idea.. I found this answer after a quick google search. I've got no experience with OpenBravo. If you want to ask a question specifically about how to do stuff in OpenBravo, I suggest you post a new question and tag it with OpenBravo. If you make it clear that your question is about openbravo, and not just a general SQL question, and then you may get someone who knows about it to help.